# Is there a way to make this Java program more interactive?

Tags: java

I have written the following very simple Java program to ask user enter a file name, then it will report the number of lines of this file to the standard output:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CountLine {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

     //  prompt the user to enter their file name
    System.out.print("Please enter your file name: ");

    //  open up standard input
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      String fileName = null;

      //  read the username from the command-line; need to use try/catch with the
      //  readLine() method
      try {
         fileName = br.readLine();
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.out.println("IO error trying to read your name!");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.out.println("Thanks for the file name, " + fileName);



    File file = new File("C:/Users/Will/Desktop/"+fileName);
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);

    int count =0;
    String currentLine;

    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        currentLine=scanner.nextLine();
        count++;

    }

    System.out.println("The number of lines in this file is "+count);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("There is no such file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

It is working.I would be really thankful if experts could help me

1. see if there is anything that can be improved in this code fragment,
2. If the file is not found, the exception is caught in the outermost catch statement and print out the stack trace. However, I think it is not very user-friendly, is there a way if the file does not exist, then the whole process restarts from beginning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a finally to do something after the exception is catch...

Comment: "whole process restarts from beginning?" For that you need to use a loop. ;)

Comment: If you use Java 7, you can replace the whole file reading part with: `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/Users/Will/Desktop/"+fileName), Charset.defaultCharset()); int count = line.size();`

Comment: User friendly? You have to give a user menu and help him/her navigate it while make a choice of user input, and thank him for using a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get some Structure in your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  string output;
  string fname = readFileName();
  if (fileValid(fname)) //Ensure FileExists
  {
     int lineCount = scaneFile(fname);   
     output = "some output text including line numbers"   
  }  
  else
  {
    output = "File Not Valid..."
  }
  //showOutput...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obvious change is to make a method `countLines(String filename)` that contains most of the code currently in main().  Obviously main() will call countLines().

Prompting for a file could live in main() or another method.

To restart on error you need a loop like:

```
filename = // read filename from stdin;
while(keepGoing(filename)) { // null check or whatever to let you out of the loop
    try {
         int numLines = countLines(filename);
         println("num lines in " + filename + "=" +numLines);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { // or just specific excpetions
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to make a GUI. I suggest you receive the path to the file as a command line parameter.

If file doesn't exist print a message and exit. That's all.

The command line will give the user the option to move up with the up-key, edit the name and run again.

**This class is named LineCounter and is the "business logic"**

```
package countlines;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LineCounter {

    private int lineCount = 0;
    public LineCounter(File file) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while(inFile.readLine() != null) {
            lineCount++;
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

    public int getLineCount() {
        return lineCount;
    }   

}
```

**This class is the "presentation logic"**

```
package countlines;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        if (args.length != 1){
            System.out.println("Usage: java countlines/Main filePath");
            System.exit(1);
        } 

        File f = new File(args[0]);

        if (!f.exists()){
            System.out.println("File "+f.getAbsolutePath()+" doesn't exist");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        if (f.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()+" is a directory");
            System.exit(2);         
        }

        LineCounter c;
        try {
            c = new LineCounter(f);
            System.out.println(c.getLineCount());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

    }
}
```